# how to store a custom config class in core data (i.e. key-value design or custom class)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Any advice on how to store a simple custom config class in core data.  Options would be I think:

1. Entity with a "key" and "value" attributes - perhaps different attributes to represent different possible types (e.g. Integer16, String etc)
2. Custom class type entity which specific attributes for each config item I want - only catch would be that you would only ever want have one record in this entity, but the benefits would be it should be more usable I think: e.g. for the "fontSize" config items it would just be once you get the 1st record back from core data:  "configRecord.fontSize".  No need to access via a key-value arrangement and then cast the result or whatever.

Comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run with my options 2 which seems to work a treat - and lieu of any suggested disadvantages (which I haven't found yet)

Answer (score 1):

If there would only ever be one of these, I am not sure why you would save this information in Core Data and not simply as NSUserDefaults. Don't get me wrong, I like Core Data a lot. But seems like a lot of overhead for what could be stored as a dictionary.

If you had many of these, then Core Data and your second option would enable easy searching, etc. But this is not the case.

In terms of "configRecord.fontSize" convenience, you could read in NSUserDefaults **into** your own custom class and provide getters/setters there - without resorting to Core Data.

Just my two cents worth ;-)

Comment: its just that I have core data in use already for the app, but just was pondering the app config entity and how to set this up